# Windows 10 upgrade - Windows on SSD, programs and files on HDD

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, ssd, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade from windows 7 to windows 10 but I want to be sure to do it properly because all my work is on this pc.

I have a installation of Windows 7 on a SSD (C:) which contains only Windows, I changed the locations of programs and files to the HDD (E:) (I don't remember how..)

So my question is what should I do to keep that working properly ? Because the software updater doesn't let me choose to keep my files and settings (just after agreeing the terms)

edit : I had to use this because Windows Update failed http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 (solution from [here](http://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-10-pc-laptop/369998-error-c1900204.html))

Thanks

Comment: You should change those locations back if you want to keep your applications and application settings.

Comment: The update should offer the chance to keep everything; Are you running the correct updater that the PC is entitle to have as a free upgrade?

Comment: I had to use this http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10  to upgrade  because windows update failed (advice from [here](http://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-10-pc-laptop/369998-error-c1900204.html))

Comment: If all of your work is on this PC, do you have backups?

Comment: Back Up, Back Up, Back Up!

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing an in-place upgrade to Windows 10 via Windows Update, then all of your files and programs should automatically be kept and continue working. Both upgrades I've done resulted in my applications continuing to work just like they did before the upgrade.

Comment: The thing is Windows Update failed so I used this http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 (recomended [here](http://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-10-pc-laptop/369998-error-c1900204.html))

Comment: @Ben That is a full reinstall of Windows. You will need to reinstall all of your applications if you're using that.

Comment: @DarthAndroid I disagree.  I used the Media Creation Tool, created the USB image and started setup.exe from my Win 7 system on three computers so far.  In the process the setup asks you if you wish to keep your data and applications.